# Evaluate Polynomial regression using cross_val_score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to use `cross_val_score` to evaluate my regression model (with `PolymonialFeatures(degree = 2)`). As I noted from different blog posts that I should use `cross_val_score` with original `X`, `y` values, not the `X_train` and `y_train`.

```
r_squareds = cross_val_score(pipe, X, y, cv=10)
r_squareds
>>> array([ 0.74285583,  0.78710331, -1.67690578,  0.68890253,  0.63120873,
    0.74753825,  0.13937611,  0.18794756, -0.12916661,  0.29576638])
```

which indicates my model doesn't perform really well with the mean r2 of only 0.241. Is this supposed to be a correct interpretation?

However, I came across a Kaggle code working on the same data and the guy performed `cross_val_score` on `X_train` and `y_train`. I gave this a try and the average r2 was better.

```
r_squareds = cross_val_score(pipe, X_train, y_train, cv=10)
r_squareds.mean()
>>> 0.673
```

Is this supposed to be a problem?

Here is the code for my model:

```
X = df[['CHAS', 'RM', 'LSTAT']]
y = df['MEDV']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)

pipe = Pipeline(
steps=[('poly_feature', PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)),
       ('model', LinearRegression())]
)
       
## fit the model
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first interpretation is correct. The first `cross_val_score` is training 10 models with `90%` of your data as train and 10 as a validation dataset. We can see from these results that the estimator's r_square variance is quite high. Sometimes the model performs even worse than a straight line.

From this result we can safely say that the model is not performing well on this dataset.

It is possible that the obtained result using only the train set on your `cross_val_score` is higher but this score is most likely not representative of your model performance as the dataset might be to small to capture all its variance. (The train set for the second `cross_val_score` is only `54%` of your dataset `90% of 60%` of the original dataset)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is Boston Housing dataset from the `sklearn.dataset` and I've taken a look at many similar projects and nobody raised this issue despite most did a similar job, just some slight differences. That's why I got so confused. Maybe I should employ a different regression algorithm though.

Comment: You might want to try to use additional features as the dataset has 13 features. Other model could also be more performant.

Comment: Sure thanks. I've just finished experimenting with different models as well as different features. The best mean R2 I could get is 0.46 using Lasso Regression with all 13 features. I also tried SVR. Thanks a lot for your help.